# WEB-приложение, приближенное к Real Time

Tags: jquery, php, java, запрос, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток!

Работаю на заводе, и внутренняя web-система система на PHP.

Но сейчас встала такая проблема: проезжает машина, её "баркод" считывается баркод-ридером и на странице отображается что внутри данной машины. Все бы ничего, если бы это все не проходило слишком долго:

Считывание -> оправление запроса в MySQL -> обработка данных -> обновление страницы -> визуализация данных.

Парой машина уже уехала, а данные только показались.

Можно ли какими другими технологиями (JAVA,C# и т.д.) ускорить вывод данных (а в идеале приблизить к realtime )?

P.S. На крайний случай, конечно, придется использовать ajax, но я сомневаюсь, что он даст значительный прирост скорости.

Comment: С чего у Вас такая реакция на PHP, проблема в реализации. Можно и на джаве написать тормознутое приложение.

Comment: ну у меня php ассоциировалось с сайтами, но ни как не с большими web-приложениями. Плюс у php много уязвимостей и т.д. - разводить холивар о PHPvsJAVAvsC#vs.. нет смысла, лучше оставим это мудрецам)

Comment: > Считывание -> оправление запроса в MySQL -> обновление страницы -> визуализация данных.

где именно в этой цепочке возникают тормоза ?

Comment: на моменте "обработка данных" и "визуализация"

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая, как вы считаете wikipedia и facebook это большие веб приложения ? (дада  я знаю про фэйсбук детали, которые вы могли бы мне сообщить, но тем не менее три года назад этих деталей ещё не было)

Comment: Если слишком долго обрабатываются данные то могу посоветовать:
1) Увеличение мощности железа (может у Вас стоит пень 133 с 32мб оперативки :-) )
2) Оптимизация самой БД ( у меня в интернет-магазине автозапчастей запросы на поиск детали по артикулу, выгребание всей инфы(размеры,фото, заменники, к каким авто подходит) выполнялись за 1-2 секунды.) . До проведения оптимизации бывало и по таймауту (600 секунд) процесс прибивался апачем .
3) Насчёт AJAXа подумайте. Выделите код который выгребает из БД информацию и выводит в html , в отдельную страницу и через AJAX подгружайте на страницу.

Comment: @eicto, вопрос стоит совсем в другом. Удалю-ка "да-да-да, у меня, как и у Вас в первое время были расширены глаза.", а то по теме только один ответ был.

Comment: и что там такого в этой обработке ? может там стоит что-то вроде 

    SELECT * FROM TABLE
    ...
    foreach ($results as $result) if ($result['code']==$code) {show_result();}

php тут не причем, скорее всего у вас очень кривая структура бд.

Comment: включите slow queries log в mysql и смотрите что  получается.

Comment: @eicto, почему-то ограничено кол-во комментариев. 
Т.е. Вы хотите сказать, что для такой простой задачи можно и не влезать в серьезные технологии - все равно не будет значительного прироста скорости?

Comment: Почему-то ограничено кол-во комментариев. 

А что если посмотреть в сторону аплетов?

Comment: ну у меня php ассоциировалось с сайтами, но ни как не с большими web-приложениями.

Comment: ну при чем тут апплеты ? структура проекта кривая, на чем вы не напишите, пока в текущем проекте не найдете узкое место, ничего у вас не выйдет с любыми технологиями... если вам так хочется пописать на java, я вас останавливать не буду :) потом только не жалуйтесь на бесцельно потраченные **годы**, к тому-же подумайте о следующем, кто это будет поддерживать, в чужом java коде еще сложнее разобраться чем в чужом php или js коде (да а почему бы не nodejs, или ruby ? или python+django, а может и erlang/lisp покатят (тоже недооцененные в web технологии))

Comment: > Почему-то ограничено кол-во комментариев. 

[Потому что вот](http://blog.hashcode.ru/search/label/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Не поместилось всё в один комментарий. Могу посоветовать проследить цепочку выполняемых функций(методов) и проставить логирование тайм штампов(записывать в файл время начала выполнения и время окончания выполнения функции). После выполнения нескольких десятков считывания/обработки/вывода проанализируйте какой кусок кода выполняется дольше всего. Вот с найденного места и начинайте оптимизацию кода. Писать с нуля интерфейс под существующую БД нужно только в том случае если существующий не соответствует требованиям и самое главное БД оптимальна(а в этом я сомневаюсь).

Comment: локализовать проблему надо. а то "у нас все тормозит, машина уже уехала" похоже на фидбэк грузчиков.

Answer (score 5):

Ни Java, ни шарп, ни PHP не дадут вам искомый результат. Надо провести обследование что там у вас происходит и где выдаются тормоза. Скорее всего у вас медленно работает запрос к мускулу и получение от него данных. Возможно тяжелая визуализация, может быть канал узкий - все что угодно может быть.

Попробуйте потрассировать каждую компоненту по отдельности:

- Сколько времени отрабатывает UI на обработку входных данных
- Сколько времени идет сигнал от декстопа до сервера
- Сколько времени сервер обрабатывает запрос
- Сколько времени UI отрабатывает результаты запроса
- Сколько времени декстоп отарабатывает визуализацию

По идее это должны быть миллисекунды. Для примера нормальная складская система порядка 100 сканеров с примитивным веб-интерфейсом, сервер (MS SQL Server) находится за 1000 км. от сканеров. Задержка от момента пыханья сканером до обратного ответа не превышает 0.3 секунд.